# How do I write a custom keybinding feature in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I set up a Phabricator code review system in my company. We develop C# applications in Visual Studio.

I have a need to navigate between Visual Studio and Phabricator. Say, if I was editing a file `E:\FHT360\Enterprise SNS Project\Enterprise360\SiteMapGenerator\Program.cs` in Visual Studio, I want one key press that leads me to `http://192.168.0.110:8051/diffusion/FHT/browse/Enterprise%20SNS%20Project/Enterprise360/SiteMapGenerator/Program.cs`.

I was thinking about macro first but figured out that it wasn't available in VS2013. Is developing a VS Extension my only option?

I also use Sublime Text and I know how to do such a thing in a few lines of Python code but in VS, I can not find an obvious way to do it.

Thanks for any suggestions.

[Update]

I used **Visual Commander** and the code is as simple as:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {       
        string phabricatorBrowseRoot = @"http://192.168.0.110:8051/diffusion/FHT/browse/";

        string path = DTE.ActiveDocument.FullName;
        var restPath =  path.Split(new char[]{'\\'}, 3)[2];
        string url = Path.Combine(phabricatorBrowseRoot, HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(restPath));

        //System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText(url);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a custom command in Visual Studio 2013 you can use [Visual Commander](http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) or [Macros for Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3fbf133-e51b-41a2-b86f-9560a96ff62b).

Comment: The author of Visual Commander! Thanks a lot. I already figured out the code in Visual Commander.